# locate byte in pdf file and read line

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I try to read pdf file. I want to use this function

```
databuffer = [file readDataOfLength : 7] but i want read all the byte in the line .
```

It mean I use `seekToFileOffset` to find the byte but I want read the line.

```
NSMutableArray      *nameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];

NSMutableArray      *nameArrayDict = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];
NSString            *path          = [[NSBundle  mainBundle] pathForResource:@"testpdf" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSString            *contents      = [NSString   stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];


    int var=[[nameArray objectAtIndex:[nameArray count]-2] intValue];

     NSFileHandle *file;
     NSData *databuffer;
     file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath: appFile];

     int i=0;
     while (file!=nil ) {
        [file seekToFileOffset: var+i];

        databuffer = [file readDataOfLength : 7];
        NSString* aStr;
        aStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: databuffer encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"%@",aStr);

        i=i+[databuffer length];
    }
```

now i try your solution but i can't show nothing!!!

```
CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage (myDocument, 1);// 2

CGPDFDictionaryRef d;

d = CGPDFPageGetDictionary(page);


CGPDFScannerRef myScanner; 

CGPDFOperatorTableRef myTable;
myTable = CGPDFOperatorTableCreate();



CGPDFContentStreamRef myContentStream = CGPDFContentStreamCreateWithPage (page);// 3




myScanner = CGPDFScannerCreate (myContentStream, myTable, NULL);// 4





CGPDFScannerScan (myScanner);// 5


CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback(myTable,  "BT", &op_BT);//Begin text object
CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback(myTable,  "ET", &op_ET);//End text object
CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback (myTable, "MP", &op_MP);
CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback (myTable, "DP", &op_DP);
CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback (myTable, "BMC", &op_BMC);
CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback (myTable, "BDC", &op_BDC);
CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback (myTable, "EMC", &op_EMC);
```

Comment: PDF files are not ASCII text.  Large parts of them are often binary and may even be compressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend not to parse your pdf in a way you like to do it.

Try to use `CGPDFScanner` ([docs here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFScanner/Reference/reference.html))

As JeremyP says: lot's of zlib compressed stuff is in a PDF file. Do search for end of lines.
Use CGPDFScanner to extract font maps, images, etc.

But is not that easy. I can tell you. :)

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/10042723/haw-i-can-parse-cgpdfarrayref-with-cgpdf